# Using python to get BLOBS and generate a new image with same image size for each of the blob

Tags: python, opencv, blob

I am new to the Python world and there is currently a new task that we desire to do use Python to detect number of blobs, generate mask for further image process.

The image we intended to detect is as following.

WiFi Logo:

[image: 1]

And we intend to generate three mask image as following. (the JPG file is exactly the mask image we desire to generate). Those mask images will be used for further image process.

WiFi Logo base icon:

[image: 2]

WiFi Logo Small Curve icon:

[image: 3]

WiFi Logo Large Curve icon:

[image: 4]

Highly appreciated.

YS

I have tried many method however fail to generate WiFi logo to those icons. Is there anyone who can share with me how to do that with python?

Answer (score 1):

I would have written this as a comment, but since I do not have enough reputation, here it goes.

You can achieve that using contours. As the image is already binarized (ensure that it is single channel), use **cv2.findContours()**. Then iterate through the contours detected and separate the blobs by drawing each contour on a brand new black image.

To get the number of blobs simply use **len()** function of the *contours* returned from cv2.findContours().

More information on how to use contours is in this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

Comment: Thanks AHFromHogwarts for sharing the guidance, I will make more study on the "contour" related parts. I now have finished the 1st part for counting the blobs and successfully. And moving to the next part of find contours of each blob and make the mask image. 
Thanks again for sharing the guidance. 
YS

Comment: Hi AHFromHogwarts, 
Again, thanks for the guidance, I now can based on the follwoing Python Scripts to finish the task.

blank = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype='uint8')
   # Create an empty file
cv.drawContours(blank, contours=contours, contourIdx= XX, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=-1)
    # drawing contour in a new file, thickness = -1 would be the key for fill the contour with desired color.
ImgFileName = "C:/tmp/Contour_" + str(XX) + ".jpg"
cv.imwrite(ImgFileName, blank)
     # save file